# Replacing a Generic Expression for Another

Tags: report

I have written, probably several hundred times, in a document (document class: report) expressions of the form `f(x,y)` (all of them in math mode), where x and y can be a multitude of possible (complex) expressions.

Now, someone pointed out that replacing those expressions by `xFy` would be a more intuitive notation, and I agree: however I don't know if there is a way to make this substitutions in a more or less automatic way, while making them by hand seems somewhat... tedious.

Of course, I could find all possible x and y I used throughout the document, and then replace `f(x,y)` with `xFy` for each of them, but that would still be a massive undertaking. Is there a simpler way to do this?

### Edit

I apparently wasn't very precise about what I am looking for: my text contains formulas such as `f(\alpha,\beta)` or `f(x+y,z)`, and I would like to know if it is possible to change them, simultaneously, to `\alpha F\beta` and `x+yFz`, respectively.

From the comments, this seems rather complex: if it helps, I think a list of the symbols used to express x and y would be rather short.

Comment: Does your editor have a search-and-replace functionality? Is your code separated into multiple files? You could use LuaLaTeX to change all occurrences of `f(x,y)` with `xFy`, but that would mean you have to switch compilers (and @Mico will help with that search-and-replace). Also, you have to be specific: You only want `f(x,y)` > `xFy`, not `f(1,2)` > `1F2` or `f(x+y,x+y)` > `(x+y)F(x+y)` or something weird like that, correct?

Comment: `sed -E 's/f\(([^,]+),([^)]+)\)/\1F\2/g' current.tex > new.tex`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Wouldn’t that produce `xF\ln y` and `xF2 + 2`?

Comment: @Davislor Depending on the input, it could produce your examples.  What are the allowable inputs and the expected outputs?  Is there a regex that could describe the x's and y's here?

Comment: @rickhg12hs No, not in general. To detect that `n-1` is illegal but `a^{i^{n-1}}` is legal, you would need a parser capable of matching curly braces. Regexes are not powerful enough for that.

Comment: @rickhg12hs However, most cases would match the pattern ` [a-zA-Z]+ ` If there are other symbols commonly used in the document, one would need to write a more complicated expression that accepts `a\alpha\beta` but not `\alphaa` and so on for every allowable command.

Comment: @Werner Yes, it does have a search-and-replace functionality, but my problem is exactly that I want to change `f(x,y)` to `xFy` while also changing expressions like `f(x+y,z)` or `f(\alpha,\beta)` to, respectively, `x+yFz` and `\alpha F\beta`.